# Node.js fs.stat not working as expected when used on module

Tags: node.js

i'm having a weird issue with fs.stat to check if a file is valid or not,
when i pass an absolute path with a variable (filePath in this case)

it appends the path of the project to the path i sent!

```
FileCompresser.CompressFile = (filePath,callback) =>{

    console.log(filePath);

    fs.stat(filePath,(err,stat)=>{
        if(err){
            callback(err,null);
            return;
        }
        var readStream = fs.createReadStream(filePath).pipe(zlib.createGzip());
        callback(null,readStream);
    });
}
```

```
AssertionError: expected Error {
  code: 'ENOENT',
  errno: -4058,
  path: 'C:\\carpetica\\NodeCompress\\‪‪C:\\carpetica\\delete.reg',
  syscall: 'stat',
  message: 'ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat \'C:\\carpetica\\NodeCompress\\‪‪C:\\carpetica\\delete.reg\''
} to not exist
```

yet if i do the following it works correctly  :

```
fs.stat("C:/carpetica/delete.reg",(err,stat)=>{
        if(err){
            callback(err,null);
            return;
        }
        var readStream = fs.createReadStream(filePath).pipe(zlib.createGzip());
        callback(null,readStream);
    });
```

but of course that is not good for testing... i send exactly the same value i hard coded there... yet i get that weird behavior.. this behavior doesn't happen when i run directly from the REPL without modules.

UPDATE:
found the culprit ( i think!), i tested with 2 paths, and the only thing different were the
' and the "" surrounding the strings

```
it("should return a compressed file",(done)=>{
    var path2 = '‪F:/ISOS/linuxmint-17.1-mate-64bit.iso';//this doesnt work!
    var path1 = "C:/carpetica/delete.reg";//but this does!


    FileCompresser.CompressFile(path2, (err,CompressedfileStream) =>{

        should.not.exists(err);
        should(CompressedfileStream).be.ok();
        done();
    });
} );
```

as soon as i wrapped path2 on double quotes it worked as intended :)

Comment: What does your `console.log()` statement output?

Comment: C:/carpetica/delete.reg

Comment: one thing to note is that i'm trying to access files in other drives, and is not working either :(, im trying to get a file on the drive F: using the absolute path and the problem persists

Comment: Did you try using backslashes instead of forward slashes (e.g. `'‪F:\\ISOS\\linuxmint-17.1-mate-64bit.iso'`)?